# Opening files in pygame error

Tags: python, pygame

I just can't figure out the problem. So i'm making a game and im using money to buy things in the game and this doesn't seem to be working. I try  to write the new spent money in the .txt file and i just get an error.

```
with open("money.txt", "r") as rm:
game_money = rm.read()
with open("money.txt", "w") as fm:
fm.write(str(game_money))

def Function():
            ............
            slowdown_price = 20
            elif action == "buy_slowdown":
            if game_money >= 20:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                game_money -= slowdown_price
                slowdown_powerup += 1
                with open("money.txt", "w") as wm:
                    wm.write(str(game_money))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Can you correct your indentation errors?

Comment: i tried everything converting integers to strings.. simply doesn't work.

Comment: always add in question **FULL** error message - there are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem, etc.

Comment: what is `slowdown_price`? `game_money` looks like it's a string. you still have indentation errors

Comment: ForceBru I tried every thing........ please help. i'm scratching my brain for a few days here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from a file results in a string. That means that `game_money` is a string that contains the characters of a number, e.g `"30"`.
You should cast the string to an integer:

```
game_money = int(rm.read())
```

Do take note that this could fail if the file does not contain just a number, but other non-numerals.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 2, which will happily compare integers with strings, so `if game_money >= 20:` works fine. However, you can't subtract an integer from a string, so `game_money -= slowdown_price` fails. Convert that value to an integer (or float) after you read it in:

```
game_money = int(rm.read())
```

or

```
game_money = float(rm.read())
```

If you use floating-point numbers, keep in mind that they aren't exact, so exact comparisons with `==` and `!=` aren't reliable.

Comment: I'm not using python 2 im using python 3.4 but this seems  to work just fine thanks.

Comment: @StrozeR - No you're not. If you were using Python 3, there would be an error when you tried to see if a string was more than an integer.

Comment: Im positive that i use Python 3.4 compiler

Comment: @StrozeR - I'm sorry, but that isn't possible, given the traceback. Try adding `print(__import__('sys').version)` somewhere in your code, and check the output.

Comment: I get the output : 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: @StrozeR - And are you doing that in a script, in the exact same way that you are running the current script? There is literally no way for Python 3 to be successfully doing `if game_money >= 20:` with `game_money` being a string, and then failing on `game_money -= slowdown_price` two lines later.

Comment: @StrozeR - Do you have Python 2 installed?

Comment: @StrozeR - Look, there's no way for your posted code to be successfully processing that line with Python 3. It is a failing error.

Comment: Try it for yourself.

Comment: @StrozeR - I have. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int). Only Python 2 will process that line without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you try to substract number `slowdown_price` from text `game_money`. You have to convert `game_money` to number first. ie.

```
game_money = int(game_money)
```